# /etc/hosts file syntax. Is it possible to set one IP for a zone?

Tags: dns, hosts

I would like to set one IP for a zone (livejournal.com)

currently I am having to directly type the subdomains like:

```
11.11.11.11 sub1.livejournal.com
11.11.11.11 sub2.livejournal.com
11.11.11.11 sub3.livejournal.com
```

etc.

I tried

```
11.11.11.11 *.livejournal.com
```

and

```
11.11.11.11 .livejournal.com
```

didn't help.

So I want to have only one line and resolve missing subdomains to IP like: `sub1000.livejournal.com` without explicitly specifying it

Comment: The word you are looking for is *domain*.

Comment: ok, that's not possible. Got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be implemented with a DNS forwarder than acts like a very basic DNS server.  The popular implementation is [Dnsmaq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), however this might be possible with services like [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) that can perform DNS filtering for you.

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not possible to use wildcards in `/etc/hosts`.

It is, however, possible to list multiple hosts on a single line so you don't have to keep copying the IP part, just append new hosts to the line:

```
11.11.11 sub1.livejournal.com sub2.livejournal.com sub3.livejournal.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Not possible. Each entry in `/etc/hosts` maps an address to one or more *specific* hostnames. There is no way to do a wildcard mapping as you desire; use a DNS server instead.